# How to reshape dataframe and take the count

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
 ID     A1 A2 A3 A4  A5 A6 A7
1       1  1  0  0   0  0  0
2       2  1  0  5   4  4  1
```

and I would to reshape and get new dataframe with frequency count

```
ID  Type  Count  
1    A1     1
2    A1     2
2    A2     1
2    A3     0 
2    A4     5
2    A5     4
2    A6     4
2    A7     1
```

I was trying transpose but it generates 2 column and 7 rows.

Comment: `transpose` is a matrix operation that flips rows to columns and columns to rows. Although similar, data.frames are tabular and supports different data types (characters, numerics, logicals) for each column, whereas matrices are "mathematical" and strictly for a single data type.

Comment: Why `1    A2     1` is not in the result?

Comment: A1-A7 are the types and ID is quadrant, so count and type varies in every quadrant.

Answer (score 2):

We can `gather` the data to long format and keep the non-zero values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -ID) %>%
  filter(value != 0)

#     ID key   value
#  <int> <chr> <int>
#1     1 A1        1
#2     1 A2        1
#3     2 A1        2
#4     2 A2        1
#5     2 A4        5
#6     2 A5        4
#7     2 A6        4
#8     2 A7        1
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "ID")[value != 0, ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, A1 = 1:2, A2 = c(1L, 1L), A3 = c(0L, 
0L), A4 = c(0L, 5L), A5 = c(0L, 4L), A6 = c(0L, 4L), A7 = 0:1), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A way of reshaping the data is with package `reshape2`.

```
df_long <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "ID")
df_long <- df_long[df_long$value != 0, ]
row.names(df_long) <- NULL

df_long
#  ID variable value
#1  1       A1     1
#2  2       A1     2
#3  1       A2     1
#4  2       A2     1
#5  2       A4     5
#6  2       A5     4
#7  2       A6     4
#8  2       A7     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea utilizing `stack` from base R, i.e.

```
subset(transform(stack(df[-1]), ID = rep(df$ID, (ncol(df) - 1))), values != 0)

#   values ind ID
#1       1  A1  1
#2       2  A1  2
#3       1  A2  1
#4       1  A2  2
#8       5  A4  2
#10      4  A5  2
#12      4  A6  2
#14      1  A7  2
```